# Difference between PriorityQueue and Queue Implementation in Java

Tags: java, interface, queue, priority-queue, comparable

I am making an implementation of an array based priorityQueue, via this interface:

```
public interface IPriorityQueue {

/**
 * Adds an element to the queue.
 *
 * @param element the element to be queued
 * @throws QueueFullException if there is no room in the queue for the new element
 */
void enqueue(Comparable element) throws QueueFullException;

/**
 * Removes the largest element.
 *
 * @return the element removed
 * @throws QueueEmptyException if the queue is empty
 */
Comparable dequeue() throws QueueEmptyException;

/**
 * Returns the number of elements in the queue.
 * @return the number of elements in the queue
 */
int size();

/**
 * Checks whether the queue is empty.
 * @return true if the queue is empty
 */
boolean isEmpty();

/**
 * Removes all elements from the queue.
 */
void clear();}
```

I would like to know what are the fundamental differences when implementing these methods if I were to use an array-based queue of generic objects instead.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You haven't posted any implementation. Only an interface (which uses raw types, which is a really bad idea). so, you're asking the difference between what and what? Why are you implementing a PriorityQueue in the first place? Java has a standard one.

Comment: This is a question that you could easily find  by googling: a queue is "first in first out" while priority queues are backed up by a data-structure that provides order such as heap or tree. Voting to close this question as too broad.

Comment: I don't understand the question properly. Can you please explain?

Answer (score 3):

From what I understood, I believe you are asking for the difference between a queue and priority queue.

**Queue:**

A queue is defined as a Data Structure that follows a stringent method of insertion and deletion (First-In-First-Out).

**Priority Queue:**

Min priority queue: It has minimum element in it's root.

Max priority queue: it has max element in it's root.

A priority queue is a Data-Structure that has elements in some oder and you can  performs these operations: Extract-Min(), Decrease-Key(), Insert(),deleteMax(), it's because priotity queue can compare things(in generic case, it implements comaparable)

Insertion and Extract-Min in a PriorityQueue can take place in any order and depends upon how the priority queue is implemented. Heap is the most "efficient" way to implement a priority queue. But the nature of implementation of a priorityqueue depends on your requirements.

Hope this helps.